# Jest done callback is not assignable to parameter of type ProvidesCallback or undefined

Tags: node.js, jestjs, typescript-typings, ts-jest

I am trying to create a test with jest and I want to use **done()** callback but Typescript is not accepting it, I tried to use type `any`, `jest.DoneCallback` or leaving it without any type but again is not working. Any solution or idea?

[image: Screenshot of error]

```
it('implements optimistic concurrency control', async (done: any) => {
  const ticket = Ticket.build({
    title: 'Concert 123423',
    price: 5,
    userId: '123'
  });
  await ticket.save();
  
  const firstInstance = await Ticket.findById(ticket.id);
  const secondInstance = await Ticket.findById(ticket.id);

  firstInstance!.set({ price: 10 });
  secondInstance!.set({ price: 15 });

  await firstInstance!.save();

  try {
    await secondInstance!.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return done();
  }
  throw new Error('Should not reach this point');
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't have an async callback with the done function. Either return a promise **or** use done. In this case you can rewrite it to expect an error and remove the done function (and the awkward backstop at the end of the callback!)

Comment: @jonrsharpe - the course I am following, is using `async` and `done()` and did the same thing as me, the first solution he gave was: `expect(async () => {
    await secondInstance!.save();
  }).toThrow();` but said that this solution does not always work well properly, and he changed to this solution I posted. I tested the first one but it did not work saying: `Received function did not throw`

Comment: As the type system is telling you, the course isn't correct, you shouldn't mix those two ways of testing async operations. If you pass a _promise_ to `expect`, you need to `await expect(promise).{resolves/rejects}.to...` per https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects.

Answer (score 7):

You choose either to use `Promise` or a callback. In your case, you want to use async/await because you are waiting for the `save()` methods before continuing in the flow.

Your code updated:

```js
it('implements optimistic concurrency control', async () => {
  const ticket = Ticket.build({
    title: 'Concert 123423',
    price: 5,
    userId: '123'
  });
  await ticket.save();
  
  const firstInstance = await Ticket.findById(ticket.id);
  const secondInstance = await Ticket.findById(ticket.id);

  firstInstance!.set({ price: 10 });
  secondInstance!.set({ price: 15 });

  await firstInstance!.save();

  try {
    await secondInstance!.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  throw new Error('Should not reach this point');
});
```

Here is an example of using the callback:

```js
it('some asynchronous test', (done) => {
  request(app)
    .get('/endpoint')
    .expect(200)
    .expect((res) => {
       // insert some code stuff here
    })
    // The callback function is passed in so it will call
    // it once it finishes the asynchronous code
    .end(done)
})
```

Also, you shouldn't have to specify the type for the callback, it should
be inferred. You can if you want though.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `async` keyword in your first line.

The second argument of the `it` function is of type `ProvidesCallback`, defined as:

```
// @types/jest/index.d.ts

type ProvidesCallback =
  | ((cb: DoneCallback) => void | undefined)
  | (() => Promise<unknown>)
```

so that means if you make the second parameter an async function, typescript will think it is the second one: `() => Promise<unknown>`. The first one is what you want, since you want to make use of the `DoneCallback`.

Comment: This is a bad answer, the test in the OP needs to be async, just changing it to sync will break the entire test, not solve the actual problem.